# Can't change Statusbar color

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to change my statusbar background color.
This is what I have:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.makeRemoteRequest()
    this.renderBar()
}
```

this is renderBar:

```
renderBar = () =>{
 return(
   <StatusBar
     backgroundColor="#553A91"
   />
 )
}
```

I tried changing the status bar color in this method because I used my render method to have a list inside my view.
This is my render method:

```
render(){
return(
  <List containerStyle={{borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0}}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({item})=>(
        <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
        subtitle={item.location.city}
        avatar={{uri: item.picture.thumbnail}}
        containerStyle={{borderBottomWidth: 0}}
      />
    )}
    keyExtractor={item=>item.email}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
    ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
    />
  </List>
);
}
```

What I tried didn't work, how can I change my status bar color?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to change status bar color out of `render()` method, react-native provide a static method `StatusBar.setBackgroundColor` to do this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest()
    StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#553A91')
}
```

But you should be cautious about this, as the documentation said:

> For cases where using a component is not ideal, there is also an
>   imperative API exposed as static functions on the component. It is
>   however not recommended to use the static API and the component for
>   the same prop because any value set by the static API will get
>   overriden by the one set by the component in the next render.

For more infomation, see the StatusBar [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar#imperative-api).

Answer (score 0):

Import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor="Color here"/>
```

Comment: I tried writing it in render method but it does not work.